# Integral of a function is 0, and function is >= 0 then the function equals 0 on its domain.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I know this statement is true with continuous functions, however, I was wondering if we can extend this to discontinuous functions also? My gut instinct tells me no as maybe you could have a piecewise functions that just existed of isolated points, but then I don't think this would be integrable, help would be appreciated!

Comment: @vadim123 i don't think strictly positive was the correct terminology. A function i am talking about for example is one where f(x) = 0 for all x on its domain.

Comment: @vadim123 $\geq 0$ is not strictly positive, isn't it non-negative?

Comment: @vadim123 yes that's what i meant to say, apologies!

Comment: For a non-negative Lebesgue-integrable function, the integral is zero if and only if the function is zero almost everywhere. One can also characterize the condition for non-negative Riemann integrable functions to have zero integral. As a concrete example, let $C$ be the Cantor set and define $f$ by $$ f(x) = \mathbf{1}_{C}(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in C \\ 0, & x \notin C \end{cases}. $$ This function is Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$ but has zero integral.